# How to pass variable to "data-target=" angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm working with angular 2 typescript and i want to create a toggle collapse list.
This is simple with single id and `data-target` but i loop throught a list so i have dynamic id names. I want to pass a variable in my `data-target` so i can reach the dynamic names of the id's. something like this:

`<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{theme.themeId}}>collapseHere </a>`
but this gives me a syntax error.

Is it possibly to pass variables with a `data-target`?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You could used attribute binding. Something like that:

```
[attr.data-target]="'#' + theme.themeId"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, was searching for how to fix this. This solved a couple of issues I had!

Comment: How should i bind with <td> tag from .ts file?

Comment: <td data-target="#newsListModal" data-toggle="modal"></td>

Comment: Thanks a lot..very nice

Comment: Works fine but we need to append some string with # like 
 if theme.themeId is integer
`[attr.data-target] = "'#somestring'+ theme.themeId"`

Answer (score 10):

Yes exactly you can use

```
*ngFor="a of Array; index as i;"
```

and

```
[attr.data-target]="'#test' + i"
```

and

```
name="test{{i}}
```

Comment: Please any way I can ad callback funtions todata-* attributes?

Comment: @Malik Sorry, I am unable to understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Alright. For instance `data-authorize="authorizeHandler"`. `authorizeHandler` is a method belonging to my component scope. Would `authorizeHandler` work?

Comment: Sorry buddy I am not sure about it

Answer (score 9):

To pass a variable in Angular 7 you can use it just like:

```
[attr.data-target] = "theme.themeId"
```